# Почему запрос с использованием WHERE по полю без индекса выполняется быстрее, чем без WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT e.name, e.manufacturer, c.name
FROM element e
JOIN category c ON e.category_id = c.id
WHERE e.manufacturer IN ('Производитель 1', 'Производитель 2')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каковы ваши доказательства?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
Проводил сравнение на таблице из 100 000 записей.
В моём конкретном примере без наложения условия затрагиваются все записи и время составляет ~780 мс, а при наложении затрагивается только то количество записей, которое будет в итоговой выборке, и время запроса ~500 мс.

Comment: может как раз потому, что в первом случае возвращаются 100к записей, а во втором меньше ...

Comment: @santavital
По сути к этому и свелся вопрос - почему затрагивается меньшее количество записей, если в одном случае необходимо просто выгрузить все записи, а в другом надо пройтись по всем и отобрать из них те, которые удовлетворяют условию

Comment: Так я и намекаю: 100к записей SQL отобрал, поместил в память - вернул; Затраты времени на помещение 100к записей в память БОЛЬШЕ чем для помещения 33к

Comment: @santavital ТС хочет сказать, что в обоих случаях должна сканироваться вся таблица, но во втором случае из **уже выбранных данных** должны отфильтроваться по условию. Думаю так

Comment: Мне кажется это плохой перевод плюс недопонимание. На картинке выведено число строк в ответе, а не число строк которые mysql «затронул». https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html *For SELECT statements, mysql_affected_rows() works like mysql_num_rows()*

Comment: «Затронул» mysql в обоих случаях все строки.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе планы выполнения для обоих запросов

Comment: 1. На клиента возвращается разное количество записей. А передача клиенту то же занимает время. 2. при наличии where по одной из таблиц оптимизатор вполне может провести сканирование только этой таблицы, а join выполнять только для тех записей, которые подошли под условие. Следовательно обращений ко второй таблице становиться меньше